# Laravel: Load only pivot additional columns without relation

Tags: laravel, pivot, many-to-many, lazy-loading

I have the following structure:

```
Charge
  id
  amount
  created_at
  ..

Payment
  id
  amount
  created_at
  ..
```

and a pivot table `charge_payment`, since one charge can be covered partially by multiple payments.

```
charge_payment
  charge_id
  payment_id
  amount
```

The `amount` column on the pivot table defines the amount that the given Payment covers for the Charge.

And I need to get only the "paid" amount for a Payment.

I have the following models:

```
// Charge.php
class Charge extends Model
{
    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Payment')->withPivot('amount');
    }
}

// Payment.php
class Payment extends Model
{
    public function charges()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Charge')->withPivot('amount');
    }
}
```

I want to be able to get only the paid amount with:

```
$payment = Payment::find(..);

$paid_amount = $payment->charges->sum('pivot.amount');
```

However, with this approach the related models are loaded from the database and I won't be needing them.

Is there a way to load only the additional pivot column without the related models?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if one Payment can be always related only to one Charge, I would advise you to change the relationship from many-to-many to one-to-many (it will be just more correct and simpler).

Than you can simple use aggregate function (in your case `withSum`) which will return you only resulting values without relationship Models.

```
$payment = Payment::withSum('payments', 'amount')->find(..);

{{ $payment->payments_sum_amount }}
```

Comment: One Payment can cover many charges. That's why there is a many-to-many relationship. However, based on the amount paid you will be able to cover all outstanding charges fully or partially.